# Откуда взялась "галиматья"?

Tags: этимология

А какое происхождение у слова "галиматья" (в смысле, "чушь", "бред")? На вопрос натолкнуло чтение шедевров из доморощенного фэнтези: [О священном мармеладе и танцующих мечах](http://dreamworlds.ru/prikoli/83810-o-svyaschennom-marmelade-i-tancuyuschih-mechah.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если верить Вики,это французское слово было введено в литературный язык Монтенем около 1580 г. в значении "jargon des galimatias - непонятный жаргон". Слово пришло из студенческого арго, в котором таким образом именовались речи - состязания на учёных диспутах, уподоблявшихся петушиным боям. Слово осмысливалось как сочетание лат. galli (род. п. от gallus -- петух) и греч. mathia -- знание. Существуют и другие версии о происхождении слова. Возможно, оно пришло во французский язык из испанского, в котором возникло под влиянием арабского "а'лима" -- "знать, быть сведущим, понимать". Арабский язык преподавался в испанских университетах уже в 16 в. Слово могло возникнуть в языке студентов, изучающих трудный и непонятный язык. Некоторые исследователи предполагают, что слово "галиматья" связано с фр. galimafree -- бурда, плохо приготовленное блюдо. Первоначально так называли рагу, наспех приготовленное из разных имеющихся под рукой продуктов. Ещё есть анекдот о французском адвокате, отличавшемся рассеянностью и говорившем скороговоркой. Защищая клиента, у которого украли петуха, он якобы сказал в своей латинской речи вместо gallus Matthiae (петух Матвея) galli Matthias (петуха Матвей). И ещё одна весёлая версия. Слово связано с именем парижского врача Галли Матье, который обладал необыкновенным даром смешить больных до такой степени, что они от смеха выздоравливали. Став популярным, этот доктор перестал принимать больных и начал рассылать своим пациентам отпечатанные листки, в заголовке которых стояло его имя, а под ним -- разные каламбуры и шутки, имевшие целительное свойство.]http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B

Comment: А шедевры из фанфиков просто чудесны! Всем советую почитать!))))

Comment: Я что-то не так делаю? По этой ссылке
"Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand."

Comment: Ссылка в ответе нерабочая. Зато в вопросе - еще какая! Я хохотала буквально до слез. Спасибо!

Comment: Да, воистину "Великий Мерлин- в прошлом мог". Пацталом...

Однако, я хоть понял, что такое "фанфики".

Comment: Не, ну не все фанфики такие))))) Я вот тоже их пишу и, смею надеяться, что они на достаточно приличном литературном уровне. А есть вообще талантливые вещи. Но большая часть, конечно, подобных шЫдевров)))))  
Я тоже хохотала до слез, причем, даже перечитывая в третий раз)))))